Azure Speech Service. Get a reference list of supported languages via API
I'm working with Azure Speech Service and it's possible to set different language for transcription via Speech SDK.
I see here is a list of supported languages for speech to text scenario. But is it possible to get this list via API/SDK call somehow?

transcription via Speech SDK. via API/SDK call is possible which sdk you are using c#, python etc

@Sampath here is a reference list of available classes in SDK I can't see anything related to list of supported languages https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech?view=azure-dotnet

For example, for the SpeechSynthesizer is a way to get supported voices GetVoicesAsync(). However, I can't see anything similar to get supported languages for SpeechRecognizer

I referred to this documentation for information on Translator Languages in Azure AI Services.

use this https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/languages?api-version=3.0 get

To get a reference list of supported languages for the Azure Speech Service via API, you can use the Azure REST API for Speech .
Use the following endpoint to list all supported languages in JSON format:
GET https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/languages?api-version=3.0


I referred to this documentation for information on Translator Languages in Azure AI Services.
Output:

Below is an example code snippet to fetch supported languages for the Azure Speech Service:
    private static async Task GetSupportedLanguagesAsync()
    {
        string endpoint = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/languages";
        string apiVersion = "3.0";
        string requestUrl = $"{endpoint}?api-version={apiVersion}";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine("Supported Languages:");
                    Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.StatusCode}");
                    string errorResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(errorResponse);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
            }








Unfortunately, it doesn't look correct, since Speech SDK for Speech recognition (speech to text) expects locale in BCP-47 format (e.g. en-US)

Gets a list of supported locales for offline transcription use this
GET {endpoint}/speechtotext/v3.2-preview.2/transcriptions/locales  .Refer to  this link  for Get all transcriptions
